# JSON VACIO AL TRAER UN ARRAY DE MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, mariadb

Hola buenas tardes mi problema es el siguiente
Tengo el siguiente archivo .php para traer un array desde una tabla de base de datos y pasarlo a un JSON para luego tomarlo desde mi aplicación móvil.
Este es el código .php.

```
<?php

include("configuracionServer.php");
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Decodifica lo recibido por JSON y lo guarda en la variable obj
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

 try
 {
    $statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT TelefonoCliente FROM Clientes");
    $statement->execute();
    $resultado = $statement->get_result();

    mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8

    $data = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($data);

    //echo json_encode(($resultado->fetch_assoc()));
 }
 catch(mysqli_sql_exception $e)
 {
        //echo "MySQLi Error Code: " . $e->getCode() . "<br />";
        echo json_encode($e->getCode()." ".$e->getMessage());
        //echo "Exception Msg: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit(); // exit and close connection.
 }

 $conn->close();
```

?>

Este archivo me trae perfectamente el dato solicitado en mi json.

```
[{"0":225997000,"TelefonoCliente":225997000},{"0":993216118,"TelefonoCliente":993216118},{"0":253624612,"TelefonoCliente":253624612},{"0":224774700,"TelefonoCliente":224774700},{"0":22795700,"TelefonoCliente":22795700},{"0":26382550,"TelefonoCliente":26382550},{"0":242458030,"TelefonoCliente":242458030},{"0":7733366,"TelefonoCliente":7733366},{"0":600624324,"TelefonoCliente":600624324}]
```

El problema sucede cuando intento traer el campo Nombre y no teléfono, cuando el json me retorna vació.

```
$statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT NombreCliente FROM Clientes");
```

Solo me sucede con el campo nombre y dirección de esa tabla
Aquí está mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor si me pueden ayudar!!!

Comment: Cómo es que en tu consulta llamas a una tabla llamada clientes, y en la captura que muestras todo sale de una tabla usuario? El nombre del campo de la tabla que muestras es `NombreUsuario`.

Comment: tienes razon me equivoque en la imagen :D como la edito?

Comment: Debajo de tu pregunta tienes una opción para [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/262294/edit), presiona ahí y podrás editar tu pregunta c:

Comment: listo :D gracias

Comment: haz probado esa consulta en mySQL? te funciona?

Comment: Si claro en mysql todo funciona perfecto

Comment: LO HE SOLUCIONADO!! el problema era las ñ en los textos ingresados a la base de datos.
Agregando justo abajo de la conexion la linea
[mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");] y listo

Comment: ¡era por tu último registro! jajajaja, puedes esperar a que SOes te dé la opción de responder tu propia pregunta y responderte, puede que en un futuro tu pregunta sea de utilidad para alguien, mejor que la respuesta esté como tal, en vez de un comentario, el crédito es tuyo :D

Comment: Igual la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con la solucion que encontraste. Aclara bien el titulo y la pregunta... y despues agrega la respuesta COMPLETA de porque esa es la solucion.

Comment: como puedo poner la respuesta como tal para ayudar a otros despues ?